# In Tiny Death Star, is there any significance to an all zero skilled bitizen?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Is there an Emperor mission or something with them?

[image]

Comment: I feel like Stass sometimes.

Comment: Don't we all . . .

Answer (score 10):

Thus far, I have seen no mission involving unskilled labor. The stats are randomly generated. And, this is just a bitizen begging to be blown out the airlock. Nothing more.

Better yet, drop them in their dream job, collect the 1 Bux, and then blow them out the airlock.

Comment: +1 for "And this is just a bitizen begging to be blown out the airlock".

Answer (score 2):

No, that person is just uniquely awful.  Now that you've shown their terribleness off to the world, evict them.

I've got one genuine Wilhuff Tarkin on my station, and I keep him around just for his awesome name.  He has a purple cape, fedora, and green shoes, and gives pedicures at the spa.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you keep him around for . . . Sure, he's clearly fabulous in his outfit, but ?huh?

Comment: It's THE WIlhuff Tarkin.  You know, the Grand Moff?

Comment: I suggested an edit to your post to make it a tiny bit clearer.  Before, I thought you kept him around to evict people or something.  That's why it didn't make sense.  And, I find it hard to believe that Grand Moff Tarkin lacks any skills.  Have you considered the possibility that he's an imposter?

Comment: Actually, The Moff is a 9 at his dream job in the spa.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Just a brag, then.  +1 for employing the Grand Moff, himself.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Scerra Iblis]

In answer to your question:  I immediately delete people like the one I have pictured above!  They are of no use in the game.

Sadly, Scerra Iblis never achieved her lifelong dream of working in the Statuary Park.  Unskilled and unattractive, she drifted about the galaxy, and landing on Tatooine thought herself lucky when she found employment scraping the poop and dismembered limbs from the bottom of a Rancor pit. Unfortunately, a young upstart Jedi named Luke Skywalker arrived at Jabba's Palace, and made her job obsolete . . . Packing up her things, she mumbled something about being better off inside a Sarlacc and left . . .

Answer (score 1):

They don't mean anything for missions, but they are still worth keeping around if you can get them in their dream job. Dream job workers double the amount they stock (and they do it in the same amount of time that a non-dream-job bitizen would.) It's better for you to have a level zero dream job bitizen working than a level nine non-dteam-job. One dream job bitizen on the floor means the lowest level item will have double stock, two dream job bitizens mean the first and second items will be double stocked, and three dream job bitizens means all three stock items will be double stocked. I don't evict anyone for being a low skill unless I still have three bitizens with that dream job.

Comment: Ya, you'll have a much better time if you set an "evict on sight" policy.  To start off, sure you can keep most of the unskilled bitizens, but you should always have at least 1 spot for someone to move in, and also 1 open job (so you can avoid the new "I find your lack of jobs disturbing" message).  My current strategy at 57 total levels is to evict anyone with less than 8 skill on their dream job, and not bother doing cross-skill jobs lower than 7.

Answer (score -1):

Well if your resident's skill is under 5, it'll take longer to make an item.  But then, if all your residents skill in the shop is 9, it will subtract 3 minutes to make 1 item.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow...the time is directly proportional to the total skill on a given floor, I don't think there's a triple-9 bonus.